# time-related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup

I'm just checking the tags related to "time stuff" (excluding "calendars" and the like). My current "check" brought me to:

- [alarm](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alarm) (x51) -- alarms generated either by the built-in Clock app or by third-party clock replacement apps
- [clock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clock) (x33) -- Clock related issues -- whith "Clock" iin the sense of "displaying the current time"
- [date-and-time](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-and-time) (x7) -- issues with date/time formats, adjusting time, time sync, daylight saving
- [time-zones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-zones) (x10) -- issues with time zones

(I just updated their corresponding tag-wikis; above descriptions are taken from the "new wikis"). But then, while checking the tagged questions, I stumbled upon [timer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timer) (x3). Do we really need this as a separate tag -- or could it be "synonymized" to either `alarm` ("countdown-timer") or `clock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the timer questions was miscategorized (I retagged it) and the others seemed to fall under the [clock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clock) app as you've said.  Merged and synonymized!

The breakdown of the other tags looks good to me.